# Save the result of the key function in a variable

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I want to save a node obtained from a key in a variable. This in order to access to the node attributes later with something like this: $variable/@attribute, but this syntax doesn't work.

**my input.xml**

```
<?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'UTF-8' ?>

<tag1>
 <tag2 id = '866' name = 't1' />
 <tag2 id = '867' name = 't2' />
 <tag2 id = '868' name = 't3' />
</tag1>
```

**my template.xsl**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
            xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
            xmlns:cms="http://www.ametys.org/schema/cms"
            xmlns:UML="org.omg.xmi.namespace.UML"
            exclude-result-prefixes="cms UML">

<xsl:key name="k" match="/tag1/tag2" use="@id"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">

  <xsl:variable name="linkedClassName">
    <xsl:for-each select="key('k', '866')">
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
     </xsl:foreach>  </xsl:variable>

         RESULT:  <xsl:value-of select="$linkedClassName/@name" />
         RESULT2: <xsl:value-of select="key('k','866')/@name"/>

 </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**my output.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 RESULT:
 RESULT2:  t1
```

The RESULT line is what I want to do but as you can see it doesn't worK.

The RESULT line is what I want to do but as you can see it doesn't work.
The RESULT2 line is the only alternative that I found, but It means call the key function (which is very slow) each time I need to access to one of the node's attribute.

Comment: I would be very surprised if calling the key function is "very slow" as the whole point of keys is to provide fast access to nodes based on the key value.  And the XSLT processor will probably be able to optimise further by cacheing the return value because you're calling it with constant parameters.  Concentrate on writing clear and readable code to start with, and worry about optimising it later if your profiling shows this to be a true bottleneck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `<xsl:variable name="v1" select="key('k', '866')"/>`, then `<xsl:value-of select="$v1/@name"/>`.